# Get-ADGroup and Get-ADGroupMember in table format for SQL

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking for assistance in getting writing a query that will pull the members for each one of the groups in the query below.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'GroupCategory -eq "Security"' -Properties ManagedBy |
  Where-Object {$_.ManagedBy -gt 0 -or $_.Notes -like "*Approval*"} |
  Select-Object Name
```

I would like the table to look something like this (Sorry about the bad table formatting):

```
GroupName | GroupMember
Sec_Domain Admins | Username 1
Sec_Domain Admins | Username 2
Sec_EnterpriseAdmins | Username 1
Sec_Enterprise Admins | Username 3
```

I'm having a hard time joining `Get-ADGroup` and `Get-ADGroupMember` together to output a table with the group and group members in a table format for uploading into SQL.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would use an LDAP filter to express your desired query more efficiently:

```
(&(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)(managedBy=*)(notes=*approval*))
```

This means "security groups where the `managedBy` attribute is populated and the `notes` attribute contains the string 'approval'". This reduces the number of results returned from the server and reduces the need to filter results using `Where-Object`.

Second, you can output a separate object for each string in the `managedBy` attribute, and output everything to CSV using the `|` character as a delimiter. Here is a full example:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)(managedBy=*)(notes=*approval*))" -Properties managedBy | ForEach-Object {
  $group = $_
  $managedBy = $_.managedBy
  foreach ( $dn in $managedBy ) {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      "name" = $group.Name
      "managedBy" = $dn
    } | Select-Object name,managedBy
  }
} | Export-Csv "Demo.csv" -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
```

The `Select-Object` after the `New-Object` is only there to reorder the properties for the CSV output and is not strictly required.

Comment: +1 for a proper LDAP query filter, although you may find that the last clause (`notes=*approval*`) is better to do in a client side filter (ie. `Where-Object`). Substring filters on non-indexed attributes are generally slow

Comment: Client-side filtering may be a very bad idea if the network connection is slow and the number of results is very large. Better to return fewer results even if the attribute is not indexed.